# ERROR: TypeError: _this._objectInstance.remove is not a function

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am beginner in ionic app development. 
I am getting response from the API latitude and longitude and I am passing it into Google maps to place the marker in map. But i am getting the error

> ERROR: TypeError: _this._objectInstance.remove is not a function.

This the type script code

```
 getLocation(item){

    console.log(item.Street);

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let postParams = {
      Street: "fortesting",
      City: "string",
      zipORpincode: "string",
      DistrictORcounty: "string",
      State: "string",
      Country: "string"
    }

   this.http.post('http://link of an API',postParams, options)
      .subscribe(
        res => {

          let dataTemp = res.json(); //dataTemp is the json object you showed me
          this.Longitude = dataTemp.Longitude; //contains a [] object with all yours users
          this.Latitude = dataTemp.Latitude;
          console.log(this.Longitude);//This is for log 
          console.log(this.Latitude );//This is for log 

          let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
            camera: {
              target: {
                lat: this.Latitude,
                lng: this.Longitude 
              },
              zoom: 18,
              tilt: 30
            }
          };

          this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);

          // Wait the MAP_READY before using any methods.
          this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)
            .then(() => {
              console.log('Map is ready!');

              // Now you can use all methods safely.
              this.map.addMarker({
                  title: 'Ionic',
                  icon: 'blue',
                  animation: 'DROP',
                  position: {
                    lat: this.Latitude,
                    lng: this.Longitude 
                  }
                })
                .then(marker => {
                  marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK)
                    .subscribe(() => {
                      alert('clicked');
                    });
                });

            });              

        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );   
  }
```

This is HTML code from which i am calling function

```
 <button ion-button block menuToggle="right" color="menu-o" 
                (click)='getLocation(results)'>
                        <div>
                            <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
                            <label>Get Location</label>
                        </div>
                </button>
```

Comment: Where do you call the `remove ` method?

Comment: This piece of code is fine, your error comes from a component calling the `remove` function. Could you find it instead ?

Comment: I have not used any remove function in my code.

Comment: The error is solved. thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `map_canvas` is the id of the HTML element where you need to create the map, you need to pass the element into the create function and not just the id.

You can refer it using [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild).

Declare a class variable

```
@ViewChild('map_canvas') mapElement;
```

Send the native element

```
      this.map = GoogleMaps.create(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
```

Source:[Github issue](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/1947#issuecomment-354777494) solution suggested by [@Faisalali23](https://github.com/Faisalali23)